# Ошибка jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError flask

Tags: python, веб-программирование, sqlite, flask

у меня есть проблема с проектом на flask.У меня имеется каркас сайта , на главной странице которого выводится список.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При переходе нажатии на один из элементов этого списка(а их тут будет много) происходит переход на его страницу, где должен отображаться ещё один список.
Однако выводится такая ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже несколько дней бьюсь над этой проблемой и не могу понять - в чем причина.

Код на python:

```
import sqlite3

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, flash, url_for
from flask_login import LoginManager, logout_user
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '/=q3|40~$<l?6($!g$0|'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///site.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
manager = LoginManager(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    sname = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.id


class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
    name_music = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    cfname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    csname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    notes = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    cmark = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    class Columnes(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
        fname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        sname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
        mark = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
        age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
        link = db.Column(db.String(100), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        link_image = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
        name_music = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)

        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Columnes %r>' % self.id

    a = list()
    sorted(a, key=lambda column: column.mark)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id


@manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(user_id)


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/sign-up', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.form["fname"]
        sname = request.form["sname"]
        age = request.form["age"]
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        rep_password = request.form["rep_password"]
        if not (fname or sname or age or email or password or rep_password):
            flash("Please , fill all fields!")
        elif len(password) < 6 or password != rep_password:
            flash("Password is incorrect!")
        else:
            hash1 = generate_password_hash(password)
            user = User(fname=fname, sname=sname, age=age, email=email, password=hash1)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return render_template('sign-up.html')


@app.route('/home')
def home():  # put application's code here
    articles = Article.query.order_by(Article.cmark.desc()).all()
    return render_template('index.html', articles=articles)


@app.route('/composition/<string:name>')
def composition(name):
    name_music = name
    article = Article.query.order_by(Article.cmark.desc()).all()
    per = 0
    for el in article:
        if el.name_music == name_music:
            per = el
    return render_template('composition.html', comp=per)


@app.route('/create-col', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_col():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.form["fname"]
        sname = request.form["sname"]
        age = request.form["age"]
        mark = request.form["mark"]
        name_music = request.form["name_music"]
        link = request.form["link"]
        link_image = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + link[32:] + "/mqdefault.jpg"
        article = Article.query.order_by(Article.cmark.desc()).all()
        column = Article.Columnes(sname=sname, fname=fname, link=link, link_image=link_image, age=age, mark=mark,
                                  name_music=name_music)
        for el in article:
            if el.name_music == name_music:
                el.a.append(column)
                break
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return render_template('column.html')


@app.route('/login_page')
def login_page():
    return render_template('base.html')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect('/home')


@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def check_login():
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.form["email"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        sqlconnection = sqlite3.Connection("site.db")
        cursor = sqlconnection.cursor()
        query1 = "SELECT email , password from User WHERE email='{email}' AND password='{password}'".format(
            email=email, password=password)
        rows = cursor.execute(query1)
        rows = rows.fetchall()
        if len(rows) == 1:
            user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first
            if user and check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                load_user(user)

                next1 = request.args.get('next')
                redirect(next1)
            else:
                flash('Login or password is not correct')
        else:
            return redirect('/login')
    else:
        flash('Please fill login and password fields!')
    return render_template('login.html')


@app.route('/create-article', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def create_article():
    if request.method == "POST":
        cmark = request.form["c_mark"]
        mark = request.form["mark"]
        cfname = request.form["c_fname"]
        csname = request.form["c_sname"]
        fname = request.form["fname"]
        sname = request.form["sname"]
        name_music = request.form["name_music"]
        link = request.form["link"]
        link_image = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + link[32:] + "/mqdefault.jpg"
        age = request.form["age"]
        notes = request.form["notes"]
        article = Article(cfname=cfname, csname=csname, cmark=cmark, notes=notes, name_music=name_music)
        column = Article.Columnes(sname=sname, fname=fname, link=link, link_image=link_image, age=age, mark=mark,
                                  name_music=name_music)
        article.a.append(column)
        db.session.add(article)
        db.session.add(column)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        return render_template('create-article.html')


@app.after_request
def redirect_to_signin(response):
    if response.status_code == 401:
        return redirect(url_for('check_login') + '?next=' + request.url)
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

И если понадобиться - мой код html, выводящий страничку определенного элемента списка:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
    <h1 style="text-align: center">{{ comp.name_music }}</h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Author: {{ comp.cfname }} {{ comp.csname}} , Verified by {{ comp.a[0].fname }} {{ comp.a[0].sname }}</h2>
    <h2 style="text-align: center">Difficulty : {{ comp.cmark }}</h2>
    <h2 style="margin-left: 300px">The link to sheets: <a href="{{ comp.notes }}" style="text-decoration: none;">Sheets</a></h2>

    <h1 style="margin-left: 100px">The top:</h1>
    {% for el in comp.a %}
    <div class="otstup">
         <div class="list-group list-group-vertical justify-content-center">
             <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-start element-list">
                 <div class="container-sm2">
                     <a href="{{ el.link }}">
                         <img src="{{ el.link_image }}" alt="erhg" width="140px" height="90px">
                     </a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="container-sm">
                     <br>
                    <h3>Исполнитель: {{ el.fname }}  {{ el.sname }}</h3>
                    <h4>Возраст: {{ el.age }}</h4>
                 </div>
             </li>
         </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Upd:вторая часть ошибки:
[image: вторая часть ошибки]

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки, вы его обрезали на самом интересном месте

Comment: @andreymal,добавил.

Comment: Так же хотелось бы добавить,что при добавлении нового элемента допустим в "Tornado" все будет выводить отлично,однако после перезагрузки локального сервера выводит вышеуказанную ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем ошибка была в том , что массив 'a' в Article не был указан в БД. Так что для решения проблемы я создал отдельную таблицу для Columnes и просто связал её с таблицей Article.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).